# get ... inside R functions

Tags: r

in R you can pass on parameters in functions using "...", e.g.

```
myfun <- function(..., cex=0.7, mytext=1:10){
plot(...)
text(...,label=mytext)
}
```

Is there a way to get the values of "..." inside the function?
Suppose you do

```
myfun(runif(10), runif(10), cex=0.3, label=1:10)
```

You will get an error because cex is set twice in text(), so nice to extract x and y from "..." for use in text(). (I know par("usr") can be used for getting x and y from the plotting device).

Comment: `ellipsesList <- list(...)` and then extract from that list.

Comment: I think you would not succeed in passing the label argument. Did you mean to write: `myfun(runif(10), runif(10), cex=0.3, mytext=1:10)`? There is the possibility of causing errors when parameters are defined twice, as might happen with that cex parameter.

Comment: Good point with the label. Changed. The whole reason for the question was to check ... for such double definitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways:

The simplest method is to use

```
dots = list(...)
```

which returns a named list of the arguments. However, this evaluates all arguments and although this is *usually* what you want, sometimes it isn’t. To get an unevaluated list of the arguments, use

```
dots = match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
```

To illustrate the difference, consider

```
f = function (...) list(...)
g = function (...) match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
```

Called as

```
f(2 + 2)
g(2 + 2)
```

Results in:

```
[[1]]
4

[[1]]
2 + 2
```